# Klein Gordon eq. expressed with Killing fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity

I have a question on the reformulation of the Klein Gordon equation in terms of Killing fields. 
Suppose we have a static spacetime with timelike Killingfield $\xi^{\mu}$
  (e.g. Schwarzschild).
Then the wave eq. ($\nabla_{\mu}\nabla^{\mu}-m^{2})\phi=0$
  can be rewritten in the following form
$$
\partial_{t}^{2}\phi=VD^{i}(VD_{i})\phi-V^{2}m^{2}\phi
$$

with $V^{2}=-\xi_{\mu}\xi^{\mu}$
  and $D_{a}$
  being the spatial covariant derivative.

Can anybody tell me how this comes about?

Comment: Is the killing field generated by a coordinate?  (i.e., $\xi_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu}t$)

Comment: Locally, you can always write the metric in the form $-g_{00}(\vec{x}) dt^2 + \sum_{i,j=1}^3 g_{ij}(\vec{x}) dx^1dx^j$, where $t$ is the parameter along the integral lines of the Killing vector ($= \partial_t$ in the given coordinates) and $\vec{x} = (x^1,x^2,x^3)$ are coordinates on a spacelike surface orthogonal to the Killing vector. In this coordinate patch KG equation takes the form you want.

Comment: Could you explain that more explicitely, please? Maybe with the Schwarzschild metric as example?

Comment: @user40852: the schwarzschild metric is already in that form.

Comment: Sure, and using the KG in Schwarzschild spacetime I indeed do get something of similar form, but I'm unable to extract the $V$. $V$ would be $1-\frac{2M}{r}$. But I thought $V$ would be something with with the Killing field...I am confused.

Comment: With the form of the metric I pointed pointed out, you always obtain $V(\vec{x})^2 = \pm g_{00}(\vec{x})$. The sign depends on your conventions about the signature of the metric. Since in the given coordinates $\partial_t = \xi$, you also have, in agreement, with your last identity $V^2= \pm g_{00}= \pm g(\partial_t,\partial_t) = \pm g(\xi, \xi)$.

Comment: Hmmm, I still don't get it. Why is $V^2=\pm g_{00}$???